# Baby Step Giant Step Algorithm for Discrete Log: Incorrect Giant Step

Tags: python, algorithm, cryptography

So I am trying to implement the Baby Step Giant Step algorithm to calculate discrete logs. Below is my code:

```
# trying to solve 8576 = 3^x (mod 53047)
p = 53047
a = 3
B = 8576

m = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(p-1)))

baby = []
giant = []
for j in range(0,m-1):
    baby.append((a**j)%p)

for k in range(0,m-1):
    val = a**(-1)%p
    val2 = val**(k*m)%p
    giant.append((B*val2)%p)
    for i in xrange(len(baby)):
        if giant[k] == baby[k]:
            x = j + m*k
```

I think there is something incorrect with my giant step because I am getting very tiny values as outputs and no matches. The correct answer is  x = 1234. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You *really* should use `pow(a,j,p)` rather than `(a**j)%p` -- which risks overflow and is otherwise terribly inefficient

Comment: Your "giant" steps are actually tiny steps.  I'm not familiar with this method, but it seems strange...`a**(-1)%p` is always going to be `1/a`, and then you raise `1/a` to a large power, and then do mod p again, but you're taking an infinitesimal number mod p, which is pointless.  Are you trying to calculate the *inverse* of a, mod p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modular inverses are not computed by taking real number inverses and then taking the modulus of the result. To find the multiplicative inverse of `a` mod `p` -- you need to find an *integer* `b` with `ab = 1 (mod p)`. This can be done either by using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm or (as a shortcut) by using Fermat's Little Theorem:

```
a**(p-1) = 1 (mod p)
```

This implies that `a**(p-2) (mod p)` *is* the inverse of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# trying to solve 8576 = 3^x (mod 53047)
p = 53047
a = 3
B = 8576
```

P should be always >B how could (a^x mod P = B and B > P) take a look a again on it

best luck